# PL/SQL : ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.table_name%TYPE value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following PL/SQL code:

```
    PROCEDURE alterTab(
        nbChar IN NUMBER)
IS

    CURSOR SQL_TABLE     IS
        SELECT TABLE_OWNER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,TYPE_METHODE,SEPARATEUR,PATTERN,ID FROM TAB_PARAM ;

  sTable                                  sys.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.table_name%TYPE;
  sOwner                                  sys.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.owner%TYPE;
  sColumn                                 sys.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE;
  sType                                 sys.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE;
  sPattern                                 TAB_PARAM.PATTERN%TYPE;
  sSeparateur                                 TAB_PARAM.SEPARATEUR%TYPE;
  sId                                 sys.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE;

  nNbTable number;
```

I can't understand what sys.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.table_name%TYPE is.  For example, if the 1st row of TAB_PARAM is like this:

`('USER','EMPLOYEE','NAME','rien','REP','','ID_USER');`

Does sTable take the EMPLOYEE value?

Comment: This is just the type that the value will be, i.e. `number`, `varchar2(100)` etc.  `%type` means it will be equivalent to whatever the value of the variable is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is saying that your `sTable` variable has the same data type as the `table_name` column in `all_tab_columns`. Up to [11gR2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_2103.htm) that would be the equivalent of doing:

```
sTable varchar2(30);
```

From [12cR1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-F218205C-7D76-4A83-8691-BFD2AD372B63.htm) the object name limit has increased, so in that version it would be the equivalent of:

```
sTable varchar2(128);
```

By using the `%TYPE` syntax for the declaration, the variable will get the appropriate size for the environment the procedure is in. If you compile it in 11gR2 or earlier it will be 30 bytes, in 12cR1 or higher it will be 128 bytes - either way it will be able to hold values from that system view, or in this case presumably from your cursor, but only when you `fetch` into it.

You can use this to reference your own tables too of course, as you are with `tab_param`. The advantage is that if a column type changes you don't have to manually go through all of your PL/SQL code and change any variables to the new type/size. It's automatic - changing the table definition will invalidate the procedure, it will be recompiled on next reference, and will pick up the new type/size automatically.

[Read more about the `%TYPE` attribute in the documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/TYPE-attribute.htm)

---

You haven't shown the rest of your procedure, but it may be that you're fetching the rows from your cursor into those variables. There's an assumption there that the `table_owner`, `table_name` and `column_name` columns in your `tab_param` table are the same data type and size as those columns in `all_tab_columns` - which may not be true. Not sure why you wouldn't use the equivalent `tab_param.column%TYPE` for those. The declaration of `sType` looks odd too; maybe that is supposed to be `tab_param.type_methode%TYPE`? (If it is you could also declare a record type as `sql_table%rowtype` instead of having one scalar variable per column, but that's going rather off-topic...)

Answer (score 2):

`ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.table_name%TYPE` is the same data type as the data type of the `TABLE_NAME` column in the `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` table.

So:

```
sTable sys.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.table_name%TYPE;
```

Will declare a variable `sTable` which has the same data type as the `TABLE_NAME` column in the `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` table. The variable has not been given a value so it will, initially, have a value of `NULL`.

If you later put a cursor row into the corresponding variables then given your example, yes, it would probably have the value of `EMPLOYEE` - however, that code is not shown in your example.